# Python: List existing values in a list

Tags: python

```
data = [{u'class': u'A'}, {u'class': u'A'}, {u'class': u'B'}]
```

I want to get a list with all existing class values in data. Is there any efficient way to sort out double values?

```
output = [{u'class': u'A'}, {u'class': u'B'}]
```

Comment: Are the keys for all the dicts always the same?

Comment: Do you mean "efficient" in small execution time for large `data` or in small memory usage or in short code or other?

Answer (score 0):

Use a set instead of a list:

```
output = set(d['class'] for d in data)
```

Comment: This doesn't yield exactly what OP asked for.

Comment: This gives a `KeyError`. Did you want to use `u'class'` rather htan `'value'`? And as someone else has pointed out, the result is not what is wanted.

Comment: Thank you RemcoGerlich, I like that.

Comment: And thank you Poke for linking, I didn't know that I should look for the words dublicate and dict.

With `list(set(i['class'] for i in data))` I get `[u'A, u'B]`.

And with `[dict(t) for t in set([tuple(d.items()) for d in data])]` I get `[{u'class': u'B'}, {u'class': u'A'}]` .

Comment: @flowerflower: you can also turn the dicts into frozendicts (same but immutable) as they can be placed into sets: `set(frozendict(d) for d in data)`. Then put `list()` around that if you want to turn it into a list again. Order isn't preserved though.